# Recommended web development plugins for web browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, web, plugins

I was wondering if anyone has a preferred set of plugins that they use on web browser which ease web development. Specifically for Javascript Debugging and on spot changing tag and applying CSS (Like no stuck up in changes and need refreshing page again)

I am just getting started with new web app with clean systen. I have installed Chrome, Firefox and have default plugin plugins in chrome but i do not find it easy to use and edit. If anyone could suggest the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dev tools shipped with browsers are very useful in most case, especially for CSS. The latest Chrome 54 (Canary) started to support JS editting too.